# How can I serialise records containing static arrays (of char) - working around RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

I need to be able to pass the same set of structures (basically arrays of different records) over two different interfaces

The first (legacy) which is working requires a pointer to a record and the record size

The second, which I am attempting to develop, is type-safe and requires individual fields to be set using Get/Set methods for each field

Existing code uses records (probably around 100 or so) with memory management being handled in a 3rd party DLL (i.e. we pass the record pointer and size to it and it deals with memory management of new records).

My original thought was to bring the memory management into my app and then copy over the data on the API call. This would be easy enough with the old interface, as I just need to be able to access `SizeOf()` and the pointer to the record structure held in my internal TList. The problem comes when writing the adapter for the new type-safe interface

As these records are reliant on having a known size, there is heavy use of `array 0..n of char` static arrays, however as soon as I try to access these via 2010-flavour RTTI I get error messages stating 'Insufficient RTTI information available to support this operation'. Standard Delphi strings work, but old short-strings don't. Unfortunately, fixing string lengths is important for the old-style interface to work properly. I've had a look at 3rd party solutions such as SuperObject and the streaming in MorMot, though they can't do anything out of the box which doesn't give me too much hope of a solution not needing significant re-work.

What I want to be able to do is something like the following (don't have access to my Delphi VM at the moment, so not perfect code, but hopefully you get the gist):

```
type
  RTestRec = record
    a : array [0..5] of char;
    b : integer;
  end;

// hopefully this would be handled by generic <T = record> or passing instance as a pointer
procedure PassToAPI(TypeInfo: (old or new RTTI info); instance: TestRec)
var
  Field: RTTIField;
begin
  for Field in TypeInfo.Fields do
  begin
    case Field.FieldType of
      ftArray: APICallArray(Field.FieldName, Field.Value);
      ftInteger: APICallInteger(Field.FieldName, Field.Value.AsInteger);
      ...
  end;
end;
```

Called as:

```
var
  MyTestRec: RTestRec;
begin
  MyTestRec.a := 'TEST';
  MyTestRec.b := 5;
  PassToAPI(TypeInfo(TestRec), MyTestRec);
end;
```

- Can the lack of RTTI be forced by a Compiler flag or similar (wishful thinking I feel!)
- Can a mixture of old-style and new-style RTTI help?
- Can I declare the arrays differently to give RTTI but still having the size constraints needed for old-style streaming?
- Would moving from Records to Classes help? (I think I'd need to write my own streaming to an ArrayOfByte to handle the old interface)
- Could a hacky solution using Attributes help? Maybe storing some of the missing RTTI information there? Feels like a bit of a long-term maintenance issue, though.

Comment: Use a string, and add an attribute that specifies the max length to be serialized.